# Avoid duplication in fetch call

Tags: reactjs, duplicates, fetch

I'm trying to avoid duplication of data using fetch.

The fetch call looks like this:

```
    const [data, setData] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const promises = urls.map((url) =>
            fetch(baseUrl + url).then((response) => {
                if (response.ok) return response.json();
                throw response
            })
        );
        Promise.all(promises)
            .then((json) => setData(json))
    }, []);

    return { data}
};

export default useFetchAll;
```

How can the fetch call be modified to  avoid duplication ?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "duplication in fetch call" - are you talking about literal, multiple `fetch` statements? Do you want to prevent the same `url` being fetched multiple times?

Comment: yes, how to prevent the same data to be fetched multiples times.

Answer (score 0):

Look into [SWR](https://swr.vercel.app) or [React Query](https://react-query.tanstack.com). Both of those libraries will give you a ton of features, including caching data.